# conversion to mbox fails

Tags: emacs, mbox

I'm going from a previous version of emacs to 23. The automatic conversion of my Rmail messages to mbox seems to work. But then no headers will display. Instead, there is the error message that 'Search failed ""'. I have searched various sites and emailed experts but have not yet found any answers. I would really like to get off the very old system I'm currently using but cannot until Rmail works minimally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about starting with empty boxes locally and do a complete pull from the server of all e-mail stored in cyberspace?

Comment: As a side note, Emacs 24.4 has been released. If you are going through the trouble of an update, you may want to consider going all the way. There are some great new features in version 24.